# Django client.cookies is empty, but when visiting the url there is clearly a CSRF token assigned as a cookie

Tags: python, django, cookies

Django 3.2, python 3.8

I have a function that forces a login so I can grab data from a protected API. Here is the code:

```
def force_client_login(client, base_url):
    url = urljoin(base_url, '/login/')
    client.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    print(client.cookies)
    csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
    login_data = {
        'username': 'HIDDEN',
        'password': 'HIDDEN',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
    }
    response = client.post(url, data=login_data)
```

For some reason, the client.cookies is printing [] / an empty array. When I visit the URL  (which I printed out and verified it is correct), I can clearly see there is a cookie and that it is the CSRF token, I can see this by looking in the browser dev console under networking and looking at the get request.

This function worked on a python 3.6 version of the same project I had running on multiple separate machines.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I had was correct, the url was http instead of https!

When clicking the lint I print out in the console (what I did to see if the link was correct), it would redirect to a https link, not give an error saying it is a http link (almost all modern browsers do this).

Lame mistake, but logging so if anyone has a similar issue down the line they can hopefully be helped by this!